# Can I freeze the mouse location when entering break mode and restore it on returning to run mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-c++, mouseover

Is there a facility in Visual Studio, when debugging a desktop app, to remember where the mouse was when I hit a break point so that i may use it in Visual Studio while stepping through code, and then snap it back to that spot when I resume execution? This would help in mouseover events and other position-sensitive workflows.

If there's not something built in, would it be possible to do this with a Visual Studio plugin? Or is there a way to install a hook such that the debugger sends my application an event or interrupt that it could use to save that state on break and restore it on resume?

Thank you.

Comment: No.  Use the remote debugger for tough cases.

Comment: That's a good idea. I might still have to tape the mouse button down for a drag, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in to the VS debugger to do this.  It's more than mouse position, there are likely subtle state changes (like focus and activation) that would be difficult to save and restore reliably.

A quick and dirty thing to do is to add some `OutputDebugString` messages to the code in question to give you clues as to what's going on internally without actually breaking the execution.  VS will show the messages in the Output window.

Comment: Thanks. That's about what I figured. I still think there ought to be a way, though, since 99% of the program state is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to come anywhere close to what you're after is to use remote debugging. You can remote debug your code running inside a virtual machine so that you don't actually need a separate physical machine.